# Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto. Imagen fue null

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estoy intentando editar registros de un catálogo, éste catálogo tiene la opción de subir una imagen pero no es un campo obligatorio. El problema es que a la hora de editar el registro, ya sea que ese registro ya tenga guardada una imagen o no, me manda error si no selecciono una imagen desde el input, es como si fuera un campo obligatorio.

El error es éste...

> Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto. Imagen fue null.

Se supone que debo llamar la imagen que está guardada en el servidor pero no sé como hacerlo.

Aquí está lo que tengo en el Controller Edificio...

```
public ActionResult Update(int id)
{
    if (Session["Usuario"] == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
    }
    else
    {
        ObtenerEdificio resp = obj.catEdificioObtener(id);
        return View(resp);
    }
}

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Update(ObtenerEdificio vm, HttpPostedFileBase Imagen)
    {
        byte[] fileBytes = new byte[Imagen.InputStream.Length];
        int byteCount = Imagen.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, (int)Imagen.InputStream.Length);
        string fileContent = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);

        ActualizaEdificio entrada = new ActualizaEdificio();
        entrada.IdEdificio = vm.IdEdificio;
        entrada.Descripcion = vm.Descripcion;
        entrada.Imagen = fileContent;

        RespuestaGeneral resp = obj.catEdificioActualiza(entrada);

        ViewBag.successMessage = resp.Mensaje;

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Edificios");
    }
```

Aquí está lo que tengo en mi View Update...

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Edificios", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(d => d.IdEdificio)
    <div class="box-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputDescripcion" class="form-control-label mt-3 ml-5">Nombre:</label>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Descripcion, "", new { @class = "ml-2", style = "color:red" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Descripcion, "", new { @type = "text", @class = "form-control ml-5", style = "width:92%" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" style="text-align:center">
            <img class="mb-3" style="width:150px; height:150px;" onerror="this.src='/ImagenesSubidas/SinImagen.jpg';" src="@Url.Content(@Model.Imagen)" id="preview" />

            <div class="box-footer">
                <label for="file-upload" class="subir">
                    <i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt"></i> Subir archivo
                </label>
                <input type="file" accept="image/*" class="block" onchange='cambiar()' style='display:none;' id="file-upload" name="Imagen" />
                <div id="info"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-footer" style="text-align:center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn block btn-success mt-3 mb-3" style="width: 30%" name="crear">Guardar <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button>
    </div>
}
```

Espero me de a entender y puedan apoyarme con mi problema. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al fin logré hacerlo y aquí dejo el código que agregué en mi Controller, por si a alguien le llega a servir...

```
string fileContent = "";
if (Imagen != null)
{
    byte[] fileBytes = new byte[Imagen.InputStream.Length];
    int byteCount = Imagen.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, (int)Imagen.InputStream.Length);
    fileContent = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
}
else
{
    ObtenerEdificio resp2 = obj.catEdificioObtener(vm.IdEdificio);

    using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        byte[] data = webClient.DownloadData(resp2.Imagen);

        using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(data))
        {
            byte[] fileBytes = new byte[mem.Length];
            int byteCount = mem.Read(fileBytes, 0, (int)mem.Length);
            fileContent = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El error se debe a que el parámetro `Imagen` del método `Update` puede llegar como `null` ya que la imagen es opcional.

Si el valor de `Imagen` es `null`,  `Imagen.CualquierPropiedad` va a dar un error.

Habría que hacer algún tipo de validación a este parámetro en caso sea nulo saltarse la parte de código que hace referencia a él.

```
if (Imagen == null)
{
   //No hacer esta parte del código
}
```

O trabajar con el operador `??`.

Comment: Sí, de echo utilicé algo así para la hora de agregar un registro pero al querer editar uno que ya tiene una imagen guardada, si lo dejo así con esa validación, me elimina la imagen de ese registro.